# how to use logical operators in OOZIE decision node?

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have requirement like first ,I have to check the whether the file exist or not in given HDFS location.

If file is exist then,I have to test size of the file greater than  200 Bytes.

based on both result i have to send email notification to user.

I can check file exist or not  with the help of below code

```
${fs:exists("/user/cloudera/trdat/test.txt")}
```

I can check file size  with the help of below code

```
${fs:fileSize("/user/cloudera/trdat/test.txt") gt 200 * B}
```

I have to create a work flow to check file is exist or not  if not exist send email notification `"file is not exist"` like that message to user.

if exist then we have to check file size is  greater than  200 Bytes. if not i have to send email notification like `"file is exist but no data"` like that message.

please help me on this.

how to use logical operators (&&,||) in  this case?

how to handle this scenarios?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use logical operators in OOZIE workflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957236/how-to-use-logical-operators-in-oozie-workflow)

Comment: Your question is very confused, and apparently, so are you. You have 3 different cases, with a clear priority. So you need a decision with 3 branches "goto SendMailA if not exists ; goto SendMailB if too small ; goto end". No need for and/or operators in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response @YoungHobbit,  Samson Scharfrichter. I got the solution

Answer (score 1):

oozie EL functions/expression are using JSP Expression Language syntax. [from oozie's doc](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4_Parameterization_of_Workflows)

You can check the [JSP 2.0 specification](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjTi7vRk-PRAhXhiFQKHZdVCkgQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fotndocs%2Fjcp%2Fjsp-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec%2F&usg=AFQjCNFABe7s4YmqW64cDDA1JPZpwYxZpg) to get the syntax.

Specifically for your question, the answer is:

```
<decision name="node_name">
  <switch>
    <case to="node_1">
      ${(fs:exists("/user/cloudera/trdat/test.txt"))
         and
        (fs:fileSize("/user/cloudera/trdat/test.txt") gt 200 * B)}
    /case>
    <default to="end"/>
  </switch>
</decision>
```

Answer (score 0):

First we need to check the decision one i.e. file exist or not.

If not exist the default file missing notification.

If file exist then only, we have to check size of the file.

if file size is less then the given size then only we have to send failure notification.

with the help below code, we can achieve the above functionality.

```
<decision name="decision1">
       <switch>
         <case to="day0">
          ${fs:exists("/user/cloudera/trdat/test.txt")}
         </case>
        <default to="FileMissing" />
       </switch>
  </decision>

 <action name="day0">
   <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
   <to>......</to>
   <subject>.....</subject>
   </email>
  <ok to="decision2"/>
  <error to="end"/>
 </action>

 <action name="FileMissing">
 ................................
</action>

 <decision name="decision2">
       <switch>
         <case to="day1">
         ${fs:fileSize("/user/cloudera/trdat/test.txt") gt 200 * B}
         </case>
        <default to="DATAMissing" />
       </switch>
  </decision>
   <action name="day1">
   <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
   <to>......</to>
   <subject>.....</subject>
   </email>
  <ok to="Ok"/>
  <error to="end"/>
 </action>

 <action name="DATAMissing">
 ................................
</action>
```